# Problema con envío de formulario con AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

Buenas tardes,

Tengo un par problemas que no he podido solucionar a la hora de enviar el formulario con AJAX.

**1. El formulario se envía varias veces si le das un click, y ya si le das todos los que puedas se enviar más veces todavía.**

EL formulario se envía con una función en el submit

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onClick="addSolInfo()">Enviar Solicitud de Información</button>
```

Esta es la función ajax:

```
function addSolInfo() {
    $(document).on('submit', '#solicitudinfo', function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({            
            type : 'POST',
            url  : '../assets/webla/solicitudinfo.php',
            data : data,
            success :  function(data) {
                $('#nuevasolicitud').modal('hide');
                $("#result").html(data).fadeIn();
                getSolInfo();
            },
            complete: function(){
               setTimeout(function() {
               }, 15000);    
            }
        });
        return false;           
    });
}
```

He pensado que probablemente se deba a que lo estoy haciendo mal, ya que en el submit llamo a la función addSolInfo() y luego en la propia función le estoy diciendo también $(document).on('submit', '#solicitudinfo', function(e) para que lo envié cuando se pulse el submit, así que he probado a quitar esa parte pero deja de funcionar el formulario.

He probado también usando e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); pero tampoco funciona y estoy un poco perdido.

**2. Al enviar el formulario, uso la función getSolInfo(); para recargar el CRUD con los datos pero además de duplicar la tabla (sale arriba todas las entradas, y abajo se vuelve a repetir), deja de funcionar el plugin DataTables y no filtra las entradas por cantidad (10, 25, 50, 100) si no que salen todas las entradas directamente.**

Este es el AJAX de getSolInfo();

```
function getSolInfo() {
    $('#tBody').html('');
    $.ajax({            
        type : 'POST',
        url  : '../assets/webla/getsolicitudes.php',
        success :  function(data) {
            $('#tBody').append(data);
            $('#solicitudinfo').DataTable();
        },
        complete: function(){
           setTimeout(function() {
           }, 15000);    
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

He probado insertando $('#tBody').html(''); para limpiar el tBody y después volverlo a imprimir, pero sigue dando los mismos problemas.

Este es el código HTML de la tabla:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="solicitudinfo" data-order='[[ 0, "desc" ]]'>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        getSolInfo();
    });

</script>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Centro</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Curso</th>
            <th>Edad</th>
            <th>Contacto</th>
            <th>Etiquetas</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tBody">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Para la parte del formulario, yo, personalmente haría que en lugar de $(document) pusieras $("#idForm") o algo que haga referencia a ese formulario. Así al hacer submit, podrás buscar el botón que envía el formulario y deshabilitarlo y evitar así enviar más de una vez los datos (o lo puedes controlar con variables, como más te guste)

Comment: Charlie yo a veces he tenido ese problema, a veces por errores en el código, a veces por motivos que no me explico. Para mí es más seguro: (1). Enviar el formulario escuchando el evento `click` del botón, mediante su id. Ejemplo: `$( "#btnActualizar" ).click(function(e) {` suponiendo que el botón tenga el id `btnActualizar`. (2). En cuanto al formulario, lo mejor es identificarlo también por su id y serializarlo, Lo puedes hacer dentro del evento `click` del botón: `e.preventDefault();
  var data = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();` a mi con eso me funciona de maravilla.

Comment: Tienes dos preguntas distintas, sepáralas.. para poder responder una  por una.

Comment: Ah, otra cosa, mis botones **son del tipo `button`**, los del tipo `submit` siempre han sido para mi un dolor de cabeza. Ejemplo del HTML que uso: `<button id="btnActualizar" type="button">Actualizar</button>` Por otra parte, para que la línea `var data = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();`  me recoja todos los datos del formulario, el botón debe estar dentro de él, por supuesto.

Comment: @A.Cedano Con el tema de enviar un formulario, me surje la duda (por el tema de repetir el envio), ¿SI ya estoy llamando en el button submit con onclick a la función, en la propia función seguiría haciendo falta $( `"#btnActualizar" ).click(function(e) ` ??

Comment: @Ali He realizado las dos preguntas en una por el tema que son de la misma índole y para no hacer tantas preguntas, pero no me importa separarlas si es necesario.

Comment: Lo que propongo es que cambies esto: `function addSolInfo() {
    $(document).on('submit', '#solicitudinfo', function(e) {   var data = $(this).serialize();` por esto: `$( "#btnActualizar" ).click(function(e) { $(this).closest('form').serializeArray(); //código... });`  **ahora la función debe terminar así `});`** como he puesto después de los tres puntos. Y el botón, en el HTML lo puedes poner simplemente así: `<button id="btnActualizar" type="button">Actualizar</button>` por algún motivo, suelo tener problemas parecidos al tuyo con los `submit`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Para la parte de `var data = $(this).serialize();` si la cambio por eso que me dices, en la parte de data: data para enviar en ajax, que pondría?

Comment: Lo mismo que tienes ahora. Esa parte almacena el contenido del formulario   en la variable `data` y lo manda vía Ajax. Yo suelo usar `serializeArray`, pero puedes dejar `serialize`, sólo que debes guardarlo usando esto: `var data = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();` o bien `var data = $(this).closest('form').serialize();`  el `closest('form')` es para acceder al formulario ya que estás escuchando el evento `click` de un botón dentro de él.

Comment: @A.Cedano He probado lo que me dices pero no funcionar, estoy mirando con el debugger pero no llega a guardar los datos del form en la variable data.

Comment: Si ya tienes un botón de tipo submit no necesitas asignarle una función de click, simplemente asigna el evento submit al formulario y lo va a tomar igual

Comment: Recuerda que el `id` del botón (no el `name`) debe coincidir con lo que tienes en jQuery. También conviene que la función esté dentro de `function` para asegurar que el DOM está cargado. O sea: `$(function() { //Desde jQuery 3 document.ready es deprecated  $( "#btnActualizar" ).click(function(e) { var data=$(this).closest('form').serializeArray(); e.preventDefault(); //código Ajax... });
});` Se supone que el botón tiene el id: `btnActualizar`.  Por otra parte, para un futuro tu llamada Ajax debería tener una opción `fail` para saber si la petición falla y usar `done` en vez de `success`.

Comment: Si, @CharlieClewer sepáralas(fíjate que solo te están respondiendo la primera) las reglas dicen que debe ser una pregunta bien concisa, no solo "problema con envío" y agrupar todos tus problemas ahí. PD: También cambia el título a  "Formulario se envía varias veces si le das un click".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo he tenido a veces problemas parecidos a este y he resuelto ambas cosas escuchando el botón por su id.

Veamos:

### HTML

Creamos el botón del tipo `button` y le quitamos el `onclick`. En cambio, le damos un `id` que debe coincidir con el código jQuery:

```
<form>
    <button id="btnEnviar" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Enviar Solicitud de Información</button>
</form>
```

### jQuery

Cuando uses elementos del DOM, asegúrate que el mismo esté cargado. Para ello usaremos `$(function() {`. También, se recomienda usar al menos `done` y `fail` para controlar el resultado de las peticiones Ajax (`success`)  es obsoleto desde jQuery3.

Por cierto, asegúrate de estar cargando tu librería jQuery en el documento, de lo contrario, todo esto sería inútil.

```
$(function() 
{ //Desde jQuery 3 document.ready es deprecated 
    $( "#btnEnviar" ).click(function(e) 
    {
        var data=$(this).closest('form').serializeArray(); 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        //código Ajax... 

        var request = $.ajax
            ({
                url: '../assets/webla/solicitudinfo.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: data,
                dataType: "html"
            });

            request.done(function( data ) 
            {
                console.log(data);
                $('#nuevasolicitud').modal('hide');
                $("#result").html(data).fadeIn();
                getSolInfo();

            });

            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) 
            {
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });

            request.complete(function() 
            {
               setTimeout(function() {
               }, 15000);    
            });

        return false; //¿?           
    });



    function getSolInfo() {
        $('#tBody').html('');

        var request = $.ajax
            ({
                url: '../assets/webla/getsolicitudes.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: data,
                dataType: "html"
            });

            request.done(function( data ) 
            {
                console.log(data);
                $('#tBody').append(data);
                $('#solicitudinfo').DataTable();

            });

            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) 
            {
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });

            request.complete(function() 
            {
               setTimeout(function() {
               }, 15000);    
            });

        return false; //¿?  
    }


});
```

### PHP

Esa es otra historia. Depura lo que te dicen los `console.log` en caso de que las peticiones Ajax tengan éxito. A  veces el problema está en que los archivos del lado del servidor no están funcionando de la manera esperada. Si tienes un  `alert` entonces revisa la url de los archivos php o los archivos mismos.

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: Por lo que he probado, no llega a enviar los datos del formulario ni a insertarlos en la DB. Además de varios errores que estaba dando, como que no encontraba la función de getSolInfo() que ya he solucionado sacando la función fuera de la primera función.

Comment: @CharlieClewer ¿El `console.log` no dice nada? ¿Seguro que los archivos PHP no tienen error? Si puedes revisa el `error_log` del servidor.